# What does the ' mean next to this vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors

I am reading through Shankar's *Quantum Mechanics* and in the first chapter I came across the notation $|0'\rangle$. I am somewhat new to linear algebra (I just learned the basics this past month and I am self-taught, so my understanding is not perhaps as broad as it would be if I'd taken a class. So anyway, I have no idea what the $'$ means, and I'd appreciate any help with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the $|0'\rangle$ that appears on page $2$, it's just another vector of the vector space. The notation $0$ is used to emphasize that we want this vector to behave exactly as the zero vector, and the $'$ is because it is, in principle, different to $|0\rangle$. But it turns out that there is exactly one zero vector, so $|0'\rangle$ is indeed $|0\rangle$.

Comment: I see what you mean; thank you. Does this symbol mean anything outside of this context, as it looks kind of familiar? (I mean within linear algebra.)

Comment: You may find $0'$ (without the bra-ket) in some algebra books in the proofs of the uniqueness of the "zero element." However, I don't think it is used in any other context.

Answer (score 1):

$|0\rangle$ is a null vector. On page 2,  $|0'\rangle$  is used to denote another (assumed) null vector in order to define it equal to the first null vector, thus implying the null vector is unique.